# StartsWith() not working with takeWhile()

Tags: javascript, string, immutable.js, startswith

I'm trying to iterate over an Immutable List and have it return a new List with any entries that start with a specific string. For the example here, I am just trying to find all of the states that begin with the letter 'D' I would expect the code below to return a List with a size of 1 and 'Delaware' as an entry, but it comes back with an empty list.

```js
const states = Immutable.fromJS([
    "Alabama",
    "Alaska",
    "Arizona",
    "Arkansas",
    "California",
    "Colorado",
    "Connecticut",
    "Delaware"]);
    
function filter() {
  const testA = 'A';
  const filteredOptions = states.takeWhile((option) =>  option.startsWith(testA));
  console.error(filteredOptions.size); // is 4 as I would expect
  
  const testD = 'D';
  const filteredOptions2 = states.takeWhile((option) =>  option.startsWith(testD));
  console.error(filteredOptions2.size); // is 0 when I expect 1
};

filter();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.2/immutable.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computer's thinking:

> Does Alamaba start with A? Yes; I'll take it and continue.
> Does Alaska start with A? Yes; I'll take it and continue.
> Does Arizona start with A? Yes; I'll take it and continue.
> Does Arkansas start with A? Yes; I'll take it and continue.
> Does California start with A? No, so I stop.
>
> Does Alabama start with D? No, so I stop.

You want `filter`, not `takeWhile`. `filter` will take all elements that satisfy the proposition; `takeWhile` only those from the start of the sequence.

Comment: Thanks, yes appreciate the answer, realized it as soon as I posted, but still appreciate it!

Comment: Indeed so :) [Rubber duckie debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) FTW!

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you just need to post to find your mistake. I realized as soon as I hit post that takeWhile exits as soon as it encounters a false. A's are working because they are the beginning of the list.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [filter](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/filter) for this

```
const statesWhichStartWithLetterD = states.filter(state => state.startsWith('D'));
console.log(statesWhichStartWithLetterD.toJS()); // ["Delaware"]
```